# What are Could / Can in future Tense?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can we use *Could* to express future tense? instated of Will/would?

e.g.

a) How we could change our plan tomorrow?

b) How we could recover our bill from him tomorrow?

Comment: You mean to express future time, not tense (English does not have a future tense). Both your sentences are ungrammatical since they require subject-auxiliary inversion: "How could we change our plan tomorrow?" / "How could we recover our bill from him tomorrow?" "Could" is typically used in conditional constructions, so I think "can" would be a better option here.

Answer (score 3):

**will** is about something that definitely will take place at some time in the future, whereas **can** is talking about the ability to do something.

> We will change our plan - *we will definitely do it*
>   We can change our plan - *we are able to do it*.

When you put the **how** question word in front of it, it weakens the difference between the two, because the question is clearly about the method we will use, rather than whether it will happen / whether we are able to make it happen.

**could** and **would** are the past tense forms of **can** and **will**. If we use a past tense to talk about a future situation, this is called a [backshift](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm). A backshift is used to indicate that we are reporting what somebody else said, or  that we are talking about a [hypothetical situation](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/unreal-past/).

> Could we change our plan? - *hypothetically, are we able to change our plan?*
>   Would we change our plan? - *hypothetically, would we consider changing our plan?*

---

Note that, when we ask a question, we invert the subject and the auxiliary verb:

> We could change our plan tomorrow. - *statement*
>   How **could we** change our plan tomorrow? - *question*